# Using PHP trying to convert str to int

Tags: php, string, forms, int

I really don't get why this isn't working, so please help. I'm trying to convert a str to an int and do if statements with it, but I can't for some reason. The code jumps right over the if statement like it's not even there???

```
<?php
$cost = $_REQUEST['cost'];
$cost = (int) $cost;

if($cost < 2){
  header('Location: page.php?say=numerror');
}
?>

<input name="cost" id="cost" type="text" class="tfield" />
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Please give a proper description of what works and what doesn't. What's the input? What's the expected and the actual behaviour?

Comment: Do a var_dump($_REQUEST['cost']); and see the content.

Comment: The code jumps right over the if statement???

Comment: This works for me. I had to surround the input tag with a form tag, though.

Comment: @yanike Are you sure you want to use `(int)` in the first place? What about a cost of $9.95?

Comment: @middus I have the system set up to receive only solid dollar amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suspicion you need:

```
if ($cost < 2) {
    exit(header('Location: page.php?say=numerror'));
}
```

Comment: Wow! I never use exit(); and it worked :) Wow! I will remember this. Now I can get back to work.

Comment: That's not your actual error though. Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` for your script.

Comment: @motto that's what I'm trying to figure out. It just doesn't work, but with the exist() it does. I need to closely examine the rest to see what's up. A work around isn't a good solution.

Comment: I figured it out. I had a break in my if statements that jumped to the very end. I redid the entire if statements and put them together and it worked. Amazing how the exit() caught it though.

Comment: There is no error being thrown.  A header() redirect does not stop execution of the code, so it keeps executing.  You must put the exit() statement to stop the execution from continuing (thus completing the redirect)

Comment: @yanike using an ide may help you to noticing that kind of small errors.

Comment: @motto I use Geany IDE currently. I build all my sites with it. It's the only lightweight IDE I like that has all the features I need on Ubuntu Linux and the color scheme is amazing and easy on the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
 $cost = $_REQUEST['cost'];
 $cost = intval($cost);

if($cost < 2){
header('Location: page.php?say=numerror');
}
?>

// HTML
<input name="cost" id="cost" type="text" class="tfield" />
```

Here is more about intval() function at   [intval() PHP reference manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php). I hope, that will be helpful.

If this not help you. Here is PHP function where you from string can separate integers.

```
<?php
function str2int($string, $concat = true) {
$length = strlen($string);   
for ($i = 0, $int = '', $concat_flag = true; $i < $length; $i++) {
    if (is_numeric($string[$i]) && $concat_flag) {
        $int .= $string[$i];
    } elseif(!$concat && $concat_flag && strlen($int) > 0) {
        $concat_flag = false;
    }       
}

return (int) $int;
}

// Callings
echo var_dump(str2int('sh12apen11')); // int(12)
echo var_dump(str2int('sh12apen11', false)); // int(1211)
echo var_dump(str2int('shap99en')); // int(99)
echo var_dump(intval('shap99en')); // int(0)
?>
```

P.S Function copied from link above. Isn't mine.

Comment: The op statement ( $cost = (int)$cost; )is good enough to work

Comment: I have nothing against you of course but who write the function str2int is a fool. He can just write a one-line function to do the same thing using regex.

Comment: @FilipKrstic I agree with Aurelio: This is not a good answer, `str2int` does not even do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

why do you need a conversion just use this:

```
<?php
$cost = $_REQUEST['cost'];
if($cost < 2 or !is_numeric($cost)){
header('Location: page.php?say=numerror');
}
?>
<input name="cost" id="cost" type="text" class="tfield" />
```